# Powershell: remove value from property by its value

Tags: powershell, ps, ps1, psobject

There is a JSON like:

```
{ a: 
   {  
      a1 : { a11:{}; a12:{}; a13:{};}; 
      a2 : {some other values}; 
    } 
  b: 
    { 
      b1:  {another values} 
    }
}
```

so then I converted it using powershell with command and put it into a variable $test

```
$test = Get-Content $some_file_path | ConvertFrom-Json
```

and then I'd like to get this JSON with some excluding from "a1". result should be like ( so I remove a13):

```
{ a: 
   {  
      a1 : { a11: {} a12: {}}; 
    } 
  b: 
    { 
      b1:  {another values} 
    }
}
```

so, if I use:

```
$test.a.PSObject.Properties["a1"].Remove("a13")
```

returns me an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty] does not contain a method named 'Remove'.
```

so, I clearly don't understand what should I do. could anyonne help me to understand?

Comment: Please provide a valid Json to demonstrate how this is done.

Comment: $test.a.PSObject.Properties.Remove('a13')  If you still have issues use Format-Table to help debug : $test.a | Format-Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.remove) is a method on the properties *collection* (`.psobject.Properties`), not on the individual *entries* in that collection (which explains the error you saw).

A simplified example:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

# Remove property .two
$obj.psobject.Properties.Remove('two')
```